# Get distinct element count from table in MySQL and local list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of strings in memory locally. I have another list of strings in a database table. I want to get a count of distinct strings in the combination of both lists. I don't want to retrieve the full list from the database

By local memory, I mean I have an array variable in PHP. But this question is not language specific.

```
$var = [ "str1", "str2" ];
```

The following won't work, because I can't bind a parameter in the locations I need.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT str) FROM
 (SELECT str FROM strs UNION ALL SELECT ? UNION ALL SELECT ?)
  AS combinedList;
```

Is there a way to do this without a temporary table that still uses parameters?

Comment: where is `memory locally` in DB or AP?

Comment: I clarified the description

Comment: It'd help to show a few examples of the values in `str` column

Comment: “str2”, “str3” - it’s pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Is it always just an array of strings? There are work arounds for that

Comment: Yes, always an array of strings.

Comment: In other RDBMS like MS SQL Sever, this is a trivial task, SQL Server has Table Valued Parameters (TVP), Table Valued Types (TVT) and Table Valued Functions (TVF) but also functions like STRING_SPLIT that allow native CSV manipulations that can help a lot here. In MySQL you are forced to use raw SQL query injection (no parameters) or temporary (or permanent) tables. It s a strong argument to grow up and out of MySQL. There are better and free alternatives out there ;)

Comment: This question is HIGHLY language specific, different languages have different calling paradigms and syntax that can each approximate the other but a solution to this will be language and library specific. Can you please edit the post to include the actual code that you are expecting to use to execute the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use variables.

This example is for two strings, but it works for any number.

```
SET @str1 = ?;
SET @str2 = ?;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT str) FROM
 (SELECT str FROM strs UNION ALL SELECT @str1 UNION ALL SELECT @str2)
  AS combinedList;
```

This gets the full benefit of parameters with no raw injection, and it uses no temp tables.